# Copy a Worksheet without losing references

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My current issue is that if i copy a worksheet in a workbook, then the copied table looses the references.

This is the code i'm using to copy the worksheet:

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Template")
Dim wa As Worksheet: Set wa = wb.Sheets("NeedToKnow")
Dim newws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, newname
'some other code to create the name
ws.Copy after:=wa: Set newws = ActiveSheet: newws.Name = newname
```

The Code above copy the worksheet "Template" and rename it with the corresponding "newname".

The Template has a table included with several columns. This columns has a Array Formula includeed:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Table1[[Costobject]:[Total]];SMALL(IF($B$3=Table1[Costobject];ROW(Table1[Costobject])-MIN(ROW(Table1[ProjectName])-1));ROW('Planning'!BI9)-8);COLUMN('Planning'!BI9)));0;INDEX(Table1[[Costobject]:[Total]];SMALL(IF($B$3=Table1[Costobject];ROW(Table1[Costobject])-MIN(ROW(Table1[ProjectName])-1));ROW('Planning'!BI9)-8);COLUMN('Planning'!BI9)))
```

So after the vba did run and copied the worksheet the Formula above is corrupted like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Table1[[Costobject]:[Total]];SMALL(IF($B$3=Table1[Costobject];ROW(Table1[Costobject])-MIN(ROW(Table1[ProjectName])-1));ROW('Planning'!#REF!)-8);COLUMN('Planning'!#REF!)));0;INDEX(Table1[[Costobject]:[Total]];SMALL(IF($B$3=Table1[Costobject];ROW(Table1[Costobject])-MIN(ROW(Table1[ProjectName])-1));ROW('Planning'!#REF!)-8);COLUMN('Resto Planning'!#REF!)))
```

Is there anyway to prevent this to happen? Or is there a automated workaround.

Currently i fix the sheets manualy when i click into the forumla CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER for Calculating the array and then use the AutocorrectOptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW(11:11); COLUMN(B:B)`. Using the [ROW](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) or 
[COLUMN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMN-function-44E8C754-711C-4DF3-9DA4-47A55042554B) function is simply returning an ordinal number into the formula. `ROW(A19)-8`, `ROW(19:19)-8`, `ROW('Planning'!BI9)-8` and `ROW(11:11)` are all the same thing; they simply result in **11**.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[[Costobject]:[Total]]; 
     SMALL(IF($B$3=Table1[Costobject]; ROW(Table1[Costobject])-MIN(ROW(Table1[ProjectName])-1)); ROW(11:11)); COLUMN(B:B))); 0)
```

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) effectively cuts your formula in half providing yu are using an .xlsx and not an .xls.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeeped Great Input. That simplifies my formula a lot. I changed it now as suggested to:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[[Costobject]:[Total]];SMALL(IF($B$3=Table1[Costobject];ROW(Table1[Costobject])-MIN(ROW(Table1[ProjectName])-1));ROW('Planning'!1:1));COLUMN('Planning'!BI:BI));0)
```

Actually it wasn't `B19` it was `BI` but your suggestion helped me to the right direction.

So now i still have the issue that when i copy the tab that the References are broken see picture below:
[Copied Sheet with broken References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umnXK.png)

Question is how i can fix this copy error?

Answer (score 0):

For the copy issue of the Template Sheet i found a solution to resolve it.

As i used the the formula in a table i converted the table to a range

I did following steps:

1. Mark the table
2. Go to Table Tools -> Design
3. Convert to Range
4. after that i marked the 1st line with the formula and populated to
   the last line (how many i ever need)

After that i didn't had any issues with broken references.